# how to Replace date with mysql query

Tags: mysql, date, replace

I need a MySQL request to replace the DATE data type. But when I use where this query doesn't work. What is not right in this query?

```
UPDATE absensi2 
SET tgl_masuk = replace(tgl_masuk, '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03'), 
 state='Update' WHERE tgl_masuk='2019-01-02' && state='NULL'
```

Thank's

Comment: Is  `$awal ` in the query been replaced by the value hold by the variable **$awal**?

Comment: Hi @YvesKipondo, yes I have replaced the varible. <pre>UPDATE absensi2 SET tgl_masuk = replace(tgl_masuk, '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03'), state='Update' WHERE tgl_masuk='2019-01-02' && state='NULL'</pre> like that query

Comment: Why didn't you replace diirectly the value of **tgl_masuk** by Setting it value to the date which you provide but you past trough the replace function. Like I can see the value of the row store in the DB attat column precisely hold "2019-01-02"

Comment: can you explain the details? Because the data that I have is> 10000. So it is not possible to replace the data one by one

Comment: You can just do `UPDATE absensi2 SET  tgl_masuk='$akhir' WHERE  tgl_masuk='$awal'. ` you don't have to use replace because you change completly th value of that column and not replace some part of that field

Comment: okay i will try @YvesKipondo. Thank's for helping.

Comment: Sure you have a char literal `state='NULL'` in that table? Why don't you just post the exact error message?

Comment: @YvesKipondo I have tried and succeeded but I still need the state = 'NULL' parameter to limit, when the parameter is added there is no updated line.

Comment: [link](https://i.imgur.com/mh4Gt31.jpg) this is an image link after the process

Comment: state is null and state = 'null' are not the same thing.

Comment: In the query which update the value of tgl_masuk, you must set all the field which need to be update. In your case tgl_masuk and state `UPDATE absensi2 SET gl_masuk='$awal', state='update' WHERE ...`. The query which I provide in the above comment was aimed to show you how to update that value directly but you must set all field which need to be update